# Prevent derived classes from hiding non virtual functions from base

Tags: c++, inheritance, method-hiding

Consider that I have classes A & B such that

```
class A
{
   public:
   void Fun();
};

class B  : public A
{
   ....
};
```

Is there any way that I as a designer of class A can enforce that derived class B and other classes which derive from A, are prevented(get a some kind of error) from hiding the non virtual function Fun()?

Comment: But you don't want to make `A::Fun()` `virtual`, am I right?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There may be some other way to solve it, but I don't think that what you describe is possible.

Comment: That should be handled by compiler. It should give you a warning on function hiding. Not that I am aware of any other possible way to prevent such behaviour.

Comment: @Mark - Yes the function is not virtual

Comment: @Mike - Having a non virtual function in the base class means that I am informing the derived class creators that they should use that implementation instead of providing their own. The problem that I am trying to solve is to make it mandatory...by some design technique if possible...Hope its clear

Comment: No client using your code should not provide their own definitions for already defined **non-virtual** functions. That is just not something that you should or need to handle. If really that is the case, then the client of your code does not know OOP basic rules.

Comment: @Adi a client can accidentally hide a name *without* providing their own definition of a parent's non-virtual function.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes i agree it can be done accidentally, but is it still the case that the class designer should handle such things? My opinion is that is not. There's a compiler warning that will be emitted in such situations and that should be enough for client to correct it's code.

Comment: @Adi unfortunately there isn't necessarily a compiler warning. Plus in the real world there are awful legacy code bases where inheritance has been wildly overused, and it is easy to miss a name amongst the zillions of inherited functions for a particular type. In well designed code, this should be less of an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the non-`virtual` member function to always be accessible in some way, then simply wrap it in a namespace scope free function:

```
namespace revealed {
    void foo( A& o ) { o.foo(); }
}
```

now clients of class B can always do

```
void bar()
{
    B o;
    revealed::foo( o );
}
```

However, no matter how much class B introduces hiding overloads, clients can also just do

```
void bar2()
{
    B o;
    A& ah = o;
    ah.foo();
}
```

and they can do

```
void bar3()
{
    B o;
    o.A::foo();
}
```

so just about all that's gained is an easier-to-understand notation and intent communication.

I.e., far from being impossible, as the comments would have it, the availability is what you have by default…

Comment: @ Alf... I dint get your answer... what I want is to enforce a rule such that all derived classes should use the base class function...and should not hide it by providing their own implementation...

Comment: @Arun: you can't force others to use *any* construct of yours. but you can refrain from providing alternatives. then if they want the functionality as provided by your implementation, they have to use the single way to do it. the answer just shows how you can always access the base class functionality. and how you can make that even easier.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf in addition to what you said, one can also write `B o; o.A::foo();`